# Create Dummy Variable with Column Transformer using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I've been trying to create a DL model for a practice purpose using ANN. I've a fake bank's customer data in which there are two categorical variable i.e gender and country.

I encode both the columns using `LabelEncoder` but not able to create dummy variables for country columns. In coutry there are three countries i.e. France, Germany and Spain.

Error I got:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

My Code:

```
# Encodeing categorical data
# for country column
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

# for gender column
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

ct = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ("dummy_var",        # Just a name
     OneHotEncoder( # The transformer class
     categories=[[1]])            # The column(s) to be applied on.
     )
], remainder='passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]
# print(X)
```

P.S: I use Pycharm and novice in Deep Learning.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistake is giving the column name inside the OneHotEncoder. It has to be given for `ColumnTransformer`.

Try this!

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ("dummy_var",        # Just a name
     OneHotEncoder(), # The transformer class
     [1]       # The column(s) to be applied on.     
     )
], remainder='passthrough')
```

Note: You don't have to apply `labelEncoder` before `OneHotEncoder`. You apply `OneHotEncoder` directly.

Comment: now it says Attribute Error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray'

Comment: Instead of using `toarray()`, you can set `sparse=False` in OneHotEncoder Instance to get a dense array